# how to remove cookie in firefox?

Tags: php, cookies

i have created a cookie with:

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie('cookiename', 'data', time()+60*60*24*365, '/', $domain, false);
```

but how do i delete it?

i tried with just switching the + to - but it didnt work.

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie('cookiename', 'data', time()-60*60*24*365, '/', $domain, false);
```

Comment: What are time zones of the server and the client?  Also, does it work in IE?

Comment: @SLaks: Cookies are based on time of the client machine, if I am not wrong.

Comment: it works in safari, but not in firefox...some other people got problems with it too...they say i have to set all parameters...but i cant create it if i add the 2 last ones...just the 3 in the beginning

Comment: @Nirmal: Yes, and the server's `time` method isn't.  That's my point.

Comment: @SLaks: OK. Got your point. So fayer must answer the question. There are chances that his system time is far way beyond!

Comment: Are you trying to delete the cookie with 'data' still being specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setcookie('fayer', FALSE, 1);
```

And make sure to use the same paramaters that you used while creating the cookie.
If you had restricted the cookie to a domain, you must mention that while deleting the cookie too.

The browser deletes the cookie only when the parameters match.

For example, if you created the cookie like this:

```
setcookie('fayer', "some value", time()+24600, "/", "www.fayer.com", 0);
```

you must delete the cookie this way:

```
setcookie('fayer', FALSE, 1, "/", "www.fayer.com", 0);
```

Comment: what if im working local. should i have the 5th argument as "localhost"?

Comment: No. 'localhost' is not a valid value. You should use false instead.